# "Scene breaks" — Blank lines that are nonblank at the top/bottom of a page

Tags: positioning, page-breaking

In many novels, a [scene break](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_break) is typeset as a blank line between paragraphs, except when that line would be the first or last on a page (and thus difficult to distinguish from the top/bottom margin), in which case it contains some fancy pattern, like three centered asterisks.  How can one define a `\sceneBreak` command in LaTeX that inserts either a blank or "fancy" line as appropriate, depending on where on the page it occurs?  I can't find any way to detect the current vertical position in LaTeX, so I've got pretty much nothing to show.

Comment: if the page breaks at the `\sceneBreak` do you want `***` at the end of the first page or top of second, or both?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If it can fit at the end of the first page, it goes there.  Otherwise, top of the second page.

Comment: If you're flexible about changing your document class `memoir` has the command `\pfbreak` that does exactly what you require.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) class provides various scene break commands. The one that does what you want is `\pfbreak`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Sample}

\lipsum[1-2]

\pfbreak

\lipsum[4]

\pfbreak

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Image of resulting page]

Comment: Again one of those little nice features from `memoir` that I'd wish existed as independent packages for us who use different classes...

Answer (score -1):

I used a \rule, but you can replace it with anything.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\scenebreak}[0]{
\par\vfill
\pagebreak[3]
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\pagebreak[3]
\vspace*{.9\textheight}
\newpage}

\begin{document}
Blah blah blah

\vspace*{5in}

before first scenebreak
\scenebreak % bottom of page

after scenebreak

\vspace*{0.95\textheight}

before second scenebreak
\scenebreak %top of next page
more stuff

\end{document}
```

Comment: I meant a command that, when it occurs in the middle of a page, inserts just a blank line, and when it occurs at the top or bottom of a page, inserts something else.  Your code inserts a rule and forces a page break no matter what.