# Customize subsection spacing at pagebreak/top of page

Tags: spacing, sectioning

I am using xelatex and the Memoir class. In this document, subsections are simply separated by two blank lines, without using any sectioning commands. If the separation occurs at pagebreak/top of page, I would like to start the new page with a line of several centered dots plus one blank line. The following MWE illustrates what I want, but I have no idea how to implement it. Any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%% Book Layout %%%
\setstocksize{9in}{6in}
\settrimmedsize{9in}{6in}{*}
\setlength{\trimtop}{0pt}
\setlength{\trimedge}{\stockwidth}
\addtolength{\trimedge}{-\paperwidth}
\settypeblocksize{7.6in}{4.8in}{*}
\setulmargins{0.5in}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{0.5in}{*}{*}
\setmarginnotes{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\checkandfixthelayout

\newcommand\mySubSecSkip{\vspace{2\onelineskip}}

%%% Document Proper %%%
\begin{document}

\vspace*{6\onelineskip}

\lipsum[1-2]

\mySubSecSkip

\lipsum[3]

{\centering
. . . . . . .\\
\mbox{}
\par}

\lipsum[4-5]

\mySubSecSkip

\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the Memoir class has a build-in command for exactly that: \pfbreak. I found it by reading the manual.

For more information, please see the answer to this question:

["Scene breaks" — Blank lines that are nonblank at the top/bottom of a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131123/scene-breaks-blank-lines-that-are-nonblank-at-the-top-bottom-of-a-page)